# How would I go about using an OnClickListener for a GridView of ImageButtons?

Tags: java, android

I have this GridAdapter that shows my working GridView of at least 100+ buttons, but all of these will need to navigate to a page once clicked. I'm unsure of how to begin or if what I have is a substantial place to start. I know where I'd put an OnClick method and listener but I am unsure of how to ensure every button in the grid is heard separately since they don't have Ids. Guides online have been helpful but I'm still lost. If anyone has some advice as to how to proceed I'd be grateful. Both java files are attached but the array of images is not included in the Adapter screenshot.

[Grid_Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4LL7.png)
[Grid_Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp5vp.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `android:onClick="[method name here]"` within the ImageButtons in your XML layout code, to call the code when each button is clicked. Note that this method has to be public and exist within the current activity.

As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- truncated -->
<Button android:id="@+id/myButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:onClick="buttonClickMethod1" />
<!-- truncated -->
```

Also note that this isn't the preferred method, and that using onClick listeners or data bindings is a better approach.

Finally, I would question your activity layout of having 100+ buttons from a user perspective - that seems very high.

Comment: I will look into this as a solution. The application is a compendium, initially there were only going to be around 50 for the sake of time, but once I had the first group in I realized it was easy to just go ahead and add all of the images that were planned to be used.

Comment: I slept on it, would it be possible for me to use switch cases in the adapter?

Say, change it to a gridView.setItemOnClickListener?

Then just have different instructions for each case?

Comment: With that approach you would still need IDs to reference your 100+ buttons. Also, you can think of a Switch statement as a giant IF statement - so I don't see how that would benefit you versus simply adding the onClick listeners in the normal way. Also, this is probably the most important: you need ALL of the onClick listeners to register when the activity loads, so that it knows when a button is clicked, so you can't add that logic in a switch statement.

Comment: What if I had it set to listen to position rather than an ID, the location of these entries won't really change. The onclick won't only be inside the switch the switch is inside the onClick, the arguments in the switch would change the fragment being shown

Comment: That might work. I found this example online: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview  If you scroll down to "Step 5" it provides an example of an onclicklistener for a GridView that you could model your code after.